# How to Convert Soap Env API Response into PHP array or JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, soap

I am facing the problem for converting Soap Env API Response into a PHP array or JSON array.
Would you guys, please, let me know how we can do it easily?
How to Convert Soap Env API Response into PHP array or JSON array?

I Got the response of API like below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns6:getLocationByCriteriaResponse xmlns:ns6="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/locations" xmlns:c="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/common" xmlns:f="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/fitments" xmlns:o="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/orders" xmlns:p="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/products">
            <ns6:locations>
                <ns6:location>
                    <ns6:locationNumber>1104464</ns6:locationNumber>
                    <ns6:locationName>CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE 1990 LTEE</ns6:locationName>
                    <ns6:phoneNumber>4507745336</ns6:phoneNumber>
                    <ns6:customerNumber>507281</ns6:customerNumber>
                    <ns6:address>
                        <c:address1>3003 RUE PICARD</c:address1>
                        <c:city>SAINT-HYACINTHE</c:city>
                        <c:state>QC</c:state>
                        <c:zipCode>J2S1H2</c:zipCode>
                    </ns6:address>
                    <ns6:servicingDC>866</ns6:servicingDC>
                </ns6:location>
                <ns6:location>
                    <ns6:locationNumber>1106909</ns6:locationNumber>
                    <ns6:locationName>CORONADO LUBE</ns6:locationName>
                    <ns6:phoneNumber>9154404222</ns6:phoneNumber>
                    <ns6:customerNumber>507281</ns6:customerNumber>
                    <ns6:address>
                        <c:address1>6508 ESCONDIDO DR</c:address1>
                        <c:city>EL PASO</c:city>
                        <c:state>TX</c:state>
                        <c:zipCode>79912</c:zipCode>
                    </ns6:address>
                    <ns6:servicingDC>615</ns6:servicingDC>
                </ns6:location>
            </ns6:locations>
        </ns6:getLocationByCriteriaResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi, 

try explode(' ', '1104464CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE 1990 LTEE45077453365072813003 RUE PICARDSAINT-HYACINTHEQCJ2S1H28661106909CORONADO LUBE91544042225072816508 ESCONDIDO DREL PASOTX79912615');

Comment: API response like - 

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns6:getLocationByCriteriaResponse xmlns:ns6="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/locations" xmlns:c="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/common" xmlns:f="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/fitments" xmlns:o="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/orders" xmlns:p="http://api.atdconnect.com/atd/3_4/products"><ns6:locations><ns6:location><ns6:locationNumber>1104464</ns6:locationNumber><ns6:locationName>CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE 1990 LTEE</ns6:locationName>........

Comment: I tried explode but it's taking this 1104464CONCORDE as one element but it should be different...

Comment: How are you making the Soap call? If you're using PHP's SoapClient, it should give you a manageable response.

Comment: I did soap call using PHP CURL

Comment: Use PHP's SoapClient instead. It's designed for making Soap calls. No reason to manually build the requests and parse the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is to convert a string to an array.

```
    $string = '1104464CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE 19905......'; // Your Responce

    $array = explode(' ', $string);

    echo '<pre>';

    print_r($array);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 1104464CONCORDE
    [1] => AUTOMOBILE
    [2] => 1990
    [3] => LTEE45077453365072813003
    [4] => RUE
    [5] => PICARDSAINT-HYACINTHEQCJ2S1H28661106909CORONADO
    [6] => LUBE91544042225072816508
    [7] => ESCONDIDO
    [8] => DREL
    [9] => PASOTX79912615
)
```

This is to convert your array to json.

```
$string = '1104464CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE 19905......'; // Your Responce
$array = explode(' ', $string); 
$json = json_encode($array); 
echo $json;



 Output: 
    [
    "1104464CONCORDE",
    "AUTOMOBILE",
    "1990",
    "LTEE45077453365072813003",
    "RUE",
    "PICARDSAINT-HYACINTHEQCJ2S1H28661106909CORONADO",
    "LUBE91544042225072816508",
    "ESCONDIDO",
    "DREL",
    "PASOTX79912615"
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but look at the below what i have concern
These 
[0] => 1104464CONCORDE
[1] => AUTOMOBILE

Should be come 

[0] => 1104464
[1] => CONCORDE AUTOMOBILE

How can we manage this?

Comment: @MikeTaylor for that I need to see the full response.